# securesocial 3.0 doesn't work with play framework 2.3

Tags: playframework-2.3, securesocial

1.When i upgrade my play framework from 2.2.6 to 2.3.8 and securesocial from 2.1.4 to 3.0-M3. I got the following error. How to fix it?

```
[error] /Work/test.scala:81: not found: value SecuredAction
[error] def findStats = SecuredAction {
```

2.The following line used to work but now it gets an error message:trait SecureSocial takes type parameters.How to fix this?

```
object ToolbarHandler extends Controller with SecureSocial with CookieLang{
```

3.Request needs a parameter.How to add the parameter though?

```
 def findStats = SecuredAction {
      implicit request =>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the snapshot version.
As stated here : http://securesocial.ws/guide/getting-started.html

add:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"
```

then add the library dependency:

```
"ws.securesocial" % "securesocial_2.11" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
```

Hope that helps.